# Calculating the value of numbers with different operations

Tags: arithmetic, problem-solving

Calculate the value of: $$-14 + 49 \times 21 - 63 + 56 \div 35 \div 28 \times 70 - 42 \div 7$$

I noticed the numbers are a factor of $7$, so I took out $7$ as a common factor:

$$7[-2 + (7 \times 3) - 9 + (8 \div 5 \div 4 \times 10) - (6\div 1)]$$
$$ = 7[-2+21-9+4-6]$$
$$ = 7[8]$$
$$ =56$$

The solution said the answer is $950$. I am not sure where I went wrong. Can somebody help please?

Comment: May I confess that I am just unable to understand the first line ? Adding parentheses were they are required would make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to factor $7a \times 7b$ as $7(a\times b)$, or $7a \div 7b$ as $7(a \div b)$.

For instance, the $49 \times 21$ term can be written as $7\times (7\times 21)$, instead.

Comment: Why not? It seems logical.

Comment: @AspiringMathlete, $7a\times 7b=7^2\times a\times b\neq 7(a\times b)$

Comment: But $7^{2} \times a \times b  = 7a \times 7b$

Comment: You took out 7 as a common factor rather than $7^2$, though.

Comment: @AspiringMathlete, yes, I demonstrated that it isn't $7(a\times b)$ which you're doing in your question. Among the four basic binary operations $+,-,\times.\div$, only $+,-$ obey distributive law, but the other two **doesn't**.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, I agree. I still think your answer could be made a little clearer by showing how to reach 950 by using your method, though.

Comment: @Mathemagician314: this is not my answer. Questions like this are nothing but knowing conventions, which here is teaching order of operations to kids. There is no real mathematics here. No (good) mathematician will ever use an expression like that in the question; it's unreadable (and arguably ambiguous). I'd write $-14+(49 \times 21)-63+\dfrac{56/35}{28}\times 70 - \dfrac{42}7=-14+(49\times 21)-63+\dfrac{56\times 70}{28\times 35}-\dfrac{42}7=950$

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the rules of operator precedence.

1. First, anything in parenthesis.
2. Then exponents.
3. Then multiplication and division.
4. Last, addition and subtraction.

(The first two don't apply to this particular situation).

Computers obey these rules. Try cutting and pasting $$-14 + 49 \times 21 − 63 + 56 \div 35 \div 28 \times 70 − 42 \div 7$$ into Wolfram Alpha. It will answer $950$, just like your answer key. There are more rules, of course, like whether to go from left to right, but just knowing operator precedence is a big step forward.